# Discrete Mathematics - Universal Instantiation Question from Prior Exam

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

For my discrete one class I had the following question on an old exam:

```
Assume that A does not contain the free variable x 

  ∀x(A → P(x)) ≡ A → ∀x P(x)
```

My professor attempted to do this on a case-by-case basis, as in what happens if A is false or if A is true and then going from there.

I am unsure how I can use that case-by-case approach to solve the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It has nothing to do with [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bi-conditional: both true or both false.

Two cases :

*(i)* $A$ is *false*.

Then $A \to Px$ is *true*, whatever $x$ is, and thus $\forall x \ (A \to Px)$ is *true*.

But if $A$ is *false*, $A \to \forall x Px$ is *true*.

*(ii)* $A$ is *true*.

Two sub-cases :

*(a)* $Px$ is *true* for all $x$. Then $A \to Px$ is *true* for all $x$, i.e. $\forall x \ (A \to Px)$ is *true*.

But if $Px$ is *true* for all $x$, also $\forall x Px$ is *true* and thus also $A \to \forall x Px$ is.

*(b)* $Px$ is *false* for some $x$. Then $A \to Px$ is *false* for some $x$, i.e. $\forall x \ (A \to Px)$ is *false*.

But if $Px$ is *false* for some $x$, also $\forall x Px$ is *false* and thus also $A \to \forall x Px$ is.

Conclusion :

> > $\forall x \ (A \to Px) \equiv A \to \forall x Px$

Answer (score 0):

In my class , I 've been taught as "Law of movement of quantifiers" that $A \rightarrow \forall x P(x) \equiv \forall x (A \rightarrow P(x))$